# Checking if a char is included in a list of letters

Tags: java, arrays, char

I'm new to Java and I want to create a boolean which checks if a char is part of a list, what is the best way of doing this?
I have tried using a enumeration but this doesn't seem to work.
Any help?

Comment: Collections (such as Lists) in java already have this functionality available. See [`Collection#contains(Object o)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#contains-java.lang.Object-). So when you have a `ArrayList<Character> yourList`, you can check if some character is part of the list like `yourList.contains('A')`. This call will return a boolean, whether the character is contained (`true`) in the list or not (`false`).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a character list. And check if this list contains the specified character.
Please see the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Character> list = Arrays.asList('H', 'E', 'L', 'L');
    System.out.println(isCharExistInList('c', list));//false
    System.out.println(isCharExistInList('H', list));//true
  }

  private static boolean isCharExistInList(char c, List<Character> list){
    return list.contains(c);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you can actually iterate over the array and check if the character you want to check is present in the array, you can do this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        //use the wrapper class (Character) and not "char"
        ArrayList<Character> theList = new ArrayList<Character>(); //declare your ArrayList
        
        //insert items to the array list
        theList.add('a');
        theList.add('b');
        theList.add('c');
        theList.add('d');

        System.out.println(doesListContain('c', theList)); //call method
    }

    public static boolean doesListContain(char c, ArrayList<Character> list) {
        boolean isFound = false; //boolean var to keep track of the availability of character in list
        try {
            for (char character : list) {
                //iterate over array list using enhanced for loop
                if(c == character){
                    //if the character is found
                    isFound = true; //set boolean to true
                    break; //stop the loop
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
        return isFound; //return the boolean variable to the caller
    }
```